# How can I put date in order when I use ggplot2

Tags: r

I am trying to put my date in order from latest to recent. I Have tried refactoring it but the dates are still in a random order

I have tried using this but it doesn't work:

```
my_data$Datum <- factor(my_data$Datum, ordered = T)
```

[This is a full pictore of what I have done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukE7N.png)

[And this is my my_data Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10Juh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you look for such a solution?

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~Datum, ~Studiepunten, 
 "1-9-2020", 0,
  "1-11-2020", 15,
  "1-1-2021", 20,
  "1-3-2021", NA,
  "1-5-2021", NA) %>% 
  mutate(Datum =  as.Date(Datum, format="%d-%m-%Y")) %>% 
  arrange(Datum)

ggplot(df, aes(x=Datum, y=Studiepunten)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_date(date_labels="%b %y",date_breaks  ="1 month") +
  expand_limits(y = 60) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you convert your dates to `Date` objects, they will be plotted in the correct order:

```
my_data$Datum <- as.Date(my_data$Datum, format = "%d-%m%-%Y")
```

You can [learn more about formatting dates here](http://www.modernstatisticswithr.com/messychapter.html#datetime).

Comment: my graph still shows a weird line like on the foto